# What is wrong that I am having this error coming while running Node.js server?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

I am getting this error while running Node.js Server:
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value " 5f04cc85d5db3f0d582fb51a" at path "_id" for model "Blog"

I have tried all possible method I know to do this but it is not working.

**This is the code from blogapp.js**
Following the RESTful Routes, I want to show more details about a particuler post when the *Read more* is clicked. But it was not working so I decided to print the error and this is what it is showing : Casterror: .....

```
var express    = require('express');
    app        = express();
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    mongoose   = require('mongoose')   
// APP CONFIG
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/restful_blog_app', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('Public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

// MONGOOSE/MODEL CONFIG
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     title:String,
     image:String,
     body: String,
     created :{type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema)
 


// RESTFUL ROUTES
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.redirect('/blogs')
})
// INDEX ROUTE
app.get('/blogs', (req,res) => {
    Blog.find({}, (err, blogs) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            res.render('blogindex', {blogs:blogs})
        }
    })
});
// NEW ROUTE
app.get('/blogs/new', (req,res) => {
    res.render('blognew')
});
// CREATE ROUTE
app.post('/blogs', (req,res) => {
    //   create blog
    
    Blog.create(req.body.blog, (err, newBlog) => {
       if(err){
           res.render('new');
       }else{
        //    then redirect to the index 
           res.redirect('/blogs')
       }
    });
});
// SHOW ROUTE
app.get('/blogs/:id', (req,res) => {
    
    Blog.findById(req.params.id , (err, Blog)=>{
      if(err){
          res.send(` ${err}`);
      }else{
        res.render('blogshow', {blog: Blog})
      }
    });
});
app.listen('5000', ()=>{
    console.log("Blog Server running on port 5000");
    
});
```

I don't know where I am getting it wrong
**This is the code from blogshow.ejs**

```
<%- include ('partials/blogheader') %>

<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header"> <%= blog.title %> </div>
</div>

<%- include ('partials/blogfooter') %>
```

Comment: What's the `_id` type on your mongoDB schema? is it string or ObjectId?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `req.params.id` contains a leading whitespace:

`" 5f04cc85d5db3f0d582fb51a"` but it should be `"5f04cc85d5db3f0d582fb51a"`

Mongoose does not trim any values and obviously cannot cast this value to an `ObjectId`.

What you could do is `Blog.findById(req.params.id.trim())` in order to make sure the whitespace is removed and/or make sure in the client-code that you're not sending the value containing whitespaces.